UniversalRouter execution reverteed BASE chain
I'm trying to use UniversalRouter to swap WETH to token, this is how i'm doing it:
    //from - WETH, to - test token
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        "0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
        UniversalRouterABI,
        wallet
    );
    let abiCoder = new ethers.utils.AbiCoder();
    let tx = await contract.populateTransaction['execute(bytes,bytes[],uint256)'](
        0x0b00, //commands
        [
            abiCoder.encode(["address", "uint256"], [
                "0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
                amount
            ]),
            abiCoder.encode(["address", "uint256", "uint256", "bytes", "bool"], [
                wallet.address,
                amount,
                0,
                ethers.utils.solidityPack(["address", "uint24", "address"], [
                    config.WETH_TOKEN.address,
                    3000,
                    config.SWAP_TOKEN.address
                ]),
                false
            ])
        ], //inputs
        1714087091, //deadline
        {
            gasLimit: 300000,
            maxPriorityFeePerGas: 330000000,
            maxFeePerGas: 330000000,
            value: amount,
        }
    );

But it gives me execution reverted tx, and i don't know what is wrong.
So i tried v2 swapping:
    let tx = await contract.populateTransaction['execute(bytes,bytes[],uint256)'](
        0x0b08, //commands
        [
            abiCoder.encode(["address", "uint256"], [
                "0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
                amount
            ]),
            abiCoder.encode(["address", "uint256", "uint256", "address[]", "bool"], [
                wallet.address,
                amount,
                0,
                [from.address, to.address],
                false
            ]),
        ], //inputs
        1714087091, //deadline
        {
            gasLimit: 300000,
            maxPriorityFeePerGas: 330000000,
            maxFeePerGas: 330000000,
            value: amount,
        }
    );

But, execution reverted tx
And i tried to as Uniswap app, with command 0x0b080604, but same tx
I really don't know, what is wrong, i tried different tokens, but there is no success.

But, i wanna tell,that it works with app.uniswap.org, so if i swap token at app.uniswap.org, and then i send SAME transaction (neck to neck), then it works tx

The tx you shared above failed because of the deadline.

Try passing the value more than block.timestamp.
You can get the block.timestamp in ethers using:
const block = await ethers.provider.getBlock('latest')
  const time = block.timestamp;

Then pass the deadline as time + 100. It should work.
You can use tenderly to trace the tx.

Wow, thanks i'll try to change deadline, and i'll try tenderly, this is cool
